# Is “flirten” used like “to flirt”?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, verb

In English, *to flirt* clearly describes an activity that can be performed both between strangers, but just as well between long-term partners.

My impression with *flirten* in German has been that it is only (or mostly) use to describe the behavior of people who are not in a romantic relationship, but they are, well, flirting with the idea of starting one (or pretending they are).

Can someone confirm or refute this impression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both, the English *to flirt*, and its German loanword *flirten* are used in the same, identical way.

#### flirten

> - jemandem durch ein bestimmtes Verhalten, durch Gesten, Blicke oder scherzhafte Worte seine Zuneigung bekunden und auf diese Weise eine erotische Beziehung anzubahnen suchen<sup>Duden</sup>
> - jmdm. vom anderen Geschlecht scherzend und unverbindlich durch Verhalten und Worte seine Zuneigung zu erkennen geben. <sup>DWDS</sup>

#### to flirt

> - to behave amorously without serious intent <sup>Mirram-Webster</sup>
> - Behave as though sexually attracted to someone, but playfully rather than with serious intentions. <sup>Oxford Dictionary</sup>

In both languages the lighthearted non-serious and playful act is a decisive element.

This however does in no way mean that couples having a long lasting relationship do not occasionally play with each other and start *flirting* again. I believe this is the same in German and in English.

Comment: I note that the German first meaning mentions “anbahnen zu suchen”, while the English first meaning says “without serious intent”. That seems to be hardly identical to me.

Comment: @JoachimBreitner: that's the Duden interpretation which does not say anything about the seriousness ... the DWDS definition is much better.

Answer (score 7):

I'll firmly disagree with the notion that *flirten* is restricted to people who are not in a romantic relationship. My marriage of 10+ years would be sad and boring if my husband and I wouldn't be occasionally flirting with each other.

Perhaps the notion that *flirten* happens only outside a relationship is based on the fact that some married or long-term couples are hesitant to show their admiration for each other in public.